# Python 3 Most Performative Way to count elements in an array binned by f(element)

Tags: python-3.x, performance, binning

Given a function:

```
def foo_bar_bazzle(x):
   # do something, could be anything
   return result
```

and an array *arr* (1 <= *len(arr)* <= 10**9) of values to evaluate using that function, I want to find the most performative way of finding the count of elements, *i* in *arr*, grouped by the value of *foo_bar_bazzle(i)*.

This gives me the correct grouped count:

```
rslt_i = {}
for i in arr:
     rslt_i.setdefault(foo_bar_bazzle(i), []).append(i)
```

allowing me to perform a non-associative operation on the len() of each foo_bar_bazzle(i):

```
return sum((len(v)**2 for v in rslt_i.values()))
```

But it isn't meeting my performance requirements. What can I do to speed up the count(x) group by f(x) here?

Comment: What you have is the most performant way. If `arr` was a numpy array / pandas dataframe and `foo_bar_bazzle` was able to operate on the entire array, then you could farm out the heavy computation to the backend but with the information provided in the question, I think you don't have any option.

Comment: Without additional assumption done, the complexity in time of the current algorithm is optimal: `O(n)`. If you want a better complexity, then you need to make an additional assumption on the target function or input array.

Comment: That being said, the code can be improved (without changing the complexity). For example, you do not need to happen `i` in a list but only count the items by incrementing a counter associated to the given key. Besides, regarding the type used, the operation can be improved further. Generic code are often slow compared to specific ones. I doubt the array type cannot be known nor the function (there are possible optimizations for integers). Still, calling `foo_bar_bazzle` 10**9 times will certainly be a bottleneck anyway in the end (CPython function calls are slow).

Comment: My takeaway here is that I should be converting arr to a numpy array and making my function work on the entire array. Thanks!